# Installing Screaming Frog (.deb package) on WSL

Tags: apt, 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running a Windows 10 computer with Ubuntu 18.04 running via the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

I am trying to install an SEO spider, [Screaming Frog](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/user-guide/general/#installation-on-ubuntu), so that I can run it in headless mode and run crawls programmatically. It appears to have been installed correctly, but when I try to run it on the command line with `screamingfrogseospider`, the following error is thrown:

```
/usr/bin/screamingfrogseospider: line 18: /usr/share/screamingfrogseospider/jre/bin//java: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be occuring?

**UPDATE**

When I run `update-alternatives --display java`

The following output is displayed:

```
java - manual mode
link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
link java is /usr/bin/java
slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Comment: It appears to need java; you can get info about what java your system is using by typing `update-alternatives --display java` in a terminal (it doesn't update anything, just gives info about which choice is in use)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for your reply! I added the output from `update-alternatives --display java` in the post.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not an expert, just trying to go through what I would do if I got this error.  It looks like java is OK, so now I would check to see if `/usr/share/screamingfrogseospider/jre/bin//java` does in fact exist.

Comment: I certainly appreciate your input! Neither `/usr/bin/screamingfrogseospider` or `/usr/share/screamingfrogseospider/jre/bin//java` exist

Comment: Well, that does explain the error message... that makes me think something went wrong with the installation.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the very same problem on ubuntu 18.04 when installing screaming frog.

I resolved it by installing last JRE :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre
```

And then fix the broken install :

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

hope this help.